# Como contar elementos de una serie sobre criterios de otra serie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Necesito contar todos los atletas de este archivo CSV que hayan participado tanto en juegos de verano como de invierno. el archivo viene de la siguiente manera:

```
Name  /  Season  
xxxxxx xxxxxx  
xxxxxx xxxxxx  
xxxxxx xxxxxx  
........... ...........
```

El problema es que me arroja un loop infinito. En mi código intento mantener el nombre e ir iterando sobre la segunda columna mientras el nombre del atleta sea el mismo, primero para temporada "winter" y luego para temporada "summer"

```
for i in pjt:
    for l,r in temp.iterrows():
        if i == r["Name"] and r["Season"] == "Winter":
            for n,m in temp.iterrows():
                if i == m["Name"] and m["Season"] == "Summer":
                    total+=1
                else:
                    break
        elif i == r["Name"] and r["Season"] == "Summer":
            for n,m in temp.iterrows():
                if i == m["Name"] and m["Season"] == "Winter":
                    total+=1
                else:
                    break
        else:
            continue
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre que usando pandas te encuentres haciendo un bucle por `iterrows` párate a pensar si no hay otra forma mejor de hacerlo. La mayoría de las veces la hay y se reduce a una línea o dos. Esto no es sólo cuestión de hacer el código más corto, sino también mucho más eficiente, puesto que si usas las primitivas pandas que operan sobre el dataframe completo "de una vez", pandas internamente hará los bucles necesarios mediante su implementación en C, mucho más rápida que si haces tus propios bucles en python.

Supongamos que partes de un Dataframe como el siguiente:

```
         Name  Season
 0        Foo  Summer
 1        Foo  Winter
 2        Bar  Summer
 3     Foobar  Autumn
 4      Xyzzy  Summer
 5    Douglas  Winter
 6     Foobar  Spring
 7    Douglas  Summer
 8  McKracken  Winter
 9    Douglas  Autumn
```

Estoy suponiendo que la columna "Season" puede tener otros valores además de Summer o Winter, como puedes ver. En la tabla anterior sólo dos nombres (Foo y Douglas) han participado en Summer y Winter.

### Idea paso a paso

El primer paso será filtrar las filas de esa tabla, para quedarse sólo con aquellas que tengan Summer o Winter en el campo Season. Este primer paso será innecesario si tu tabla ya es así.

Para ello miramos la columna `Season` y aplicamos sobre ella `.str` para obtener una versión "string" de esa columna que nos proporcione operaciones vectoriales, como `.match()` que aplica una expresión regular a todas las filas a la vez. Usaremos este método para ver cuáles encajan con la expresión regular `"Summer|Winter"`:

```
>>> df.Season.str.match("Summer|Winter")
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
9    False
```

Si usamos la anterior expresión entre corchetes en un `df[expresion]`, se seleccionarán tan solo las filas que tengan `True`, es decir, las de los nombres que hayan participado en Summer o Winter:

```
>>> df[df.Season.str.match("Summer|Winter")]
         Name  Season
 0        Foo  Summer
 1        Foo  Winter
 2        Bar  Summer
 4      Xyzzy  Summer
 5    Douglas  Winter
 7    Douglas  Summer
 8  McKracken  Winter
```

Ahora podemos hacer un `.groupby("Name")` para que agrupe los nombres repetidos, y un `.count()` sobre el resultado para que cuente cuántas veces aparece cada nombre:

```
>>> df[df.Season.str.match("Summer|Winter")].groupby("Name").count()
            Season
 Name             
 Bar             1
 Douglas         2
 Foo             2
 McKracken       1
 Xyzzy           1
```

Los que tengan un 2 en esa columna son aquellos que han participado en ambas, Summer y Winter. Por tanto podemos recoger lo anterior en una variable y usarla como filtro para quedarnos con los nombres en cuestión:

```
>>> summer_or_winter = df[df.Season.str.match("Summer|Winter")].groupby("Name").count()
>>> summer_or_winter[summer_or_winter.Season == 2]
          Season
 Name           
 Douglas       2
 Foo           2
```

Y ahí los tienes, los buenos de Foo y Douglas.

Si tan sólo quieres saber cuántos atletas son, basta aplicar un `.count()` al resultado. Esto te devuelve una serie de un solo elemento con el número buscado. Basta tomar por tanto el primer elemento de esa serie:

```
>>> summer_or_winter[summer_or_winter.Season == 2].count()[0]
2
```

## Todo junto

Se queda en un par de líneas:

```
summer_or_winter = df[df.Season.str.match("Summer|Winter")].groupby("Name").count()
total = summer_or_winter[summer_or_winter.Season == 2].count()[0]
```

Comment: Gracias máquina! Simplificado Absolutamente

Comment: Una cosa más! Como puedo usar el resultado del código?? cuando intento darle print() me indica que es método, igual que cuando trato de operarlo con otro int!!

Comment: El resultado, en la versión final que puse en dos líneas, está en `total`. Esa variable debe ser de tipo `int`. Si no es así, algo está fallando, quizás que tu dataframe no tiene la estructura que yo supuse en mi código. Si no consigues resolverlo mejor pones otra pregunta.